# Web scraping by BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python

I tried to retrieve table data through the link below by python, unfortunately they brought all the html tags but haven't brought the table. Could you do me a favor and help me.

https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/pub/71-607-x/2021004/exp-eng.htm?r1=(1)&r2=0&r3=0&r4=12&r5=0&r7=0&r8=2022-02-01&r9=2022-02-01

my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/pub/71-607-x/2021004/exp-eng.htm?r1=(1)&r2=0&r3=0&r4=12&r5=0&r7=0&r8=2022-02-01&r9=2022-02-01'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

Comment: That we site is entirely dynamic.  The page is built on the fly using Javascript.  `requests` doesn't execute Javascript.  You would have to use something like Selenium to run a real browser.

Comment: @TimRoberts Playwright, these days... :) But OP could also look at the requests the site makes in the dev tools and just retrieve the data.